# Can't use newInstance() in scala scripts

Tags: scala

When running the following as as scala script I get an InstantiationException. But when put it inside an class extending App and then compiling with scalac and running with scala it works. Any ideas?

```
class A
val foo = classOf[A]
foo.newInstance()
```

Comment: With my scala 2.10.2 in the scala command line I get `res0: A = A@1816741`, so it seems to work on my system. Which version do you use?

Comment: I've tried with 2.10.1 and 2.10.3. Note that it works in the REPL but not in a scala script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Try `foo.getConstructors()(0).newInstance(this)`, or use your own [multiline shebang](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiline_shebang)

---

The InstantiationException suggests that your call newInstance() is invoking a non-existent constructor.

Here is a similar script, printing your constructors:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
class A
val foo = classOf[A]
foo.getConstructors.foreach(c => println("Constructor: " + c))
```

Producing:

```
Constructor: public Main$$anon$1$A(Main$$anon$1)
```

Thus, an instance of an anonymous class must be passed to A's constructor.

It turns out, Scala scripts are run by a ScriptRunner, that wraps your script with an anonymous object (adapted from [scala source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/47562e7adbf8577789b3432f4bfbb36d786c6b32/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Parsers.scala#L368), and [Programming Scala](http://techbus.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/scala/9780596801908/scala-tools-libraries-and-ide-support/349)):

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    new AnyRef {
      // Your script code is inserted here.
    }
  }
}
```

Thus passing the instance of your outer anonymous class, `this`, to A's constructor allows instantiation of your new instance of inner class A.

As far as I know, there's no way to create a static inner class [within the scala language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302206/why-doesnt-scala-have-static-members-inside-a-class). Any constructors (created by the scala compiler) in a basic script will require the outer instance. The other options, that I'm aware of, include bytecode manipulation to dynamically create a new constructor for the class (way overkill, imho), or reimplementing the ScriptRunner.

During the single exec line in the shell script, Scala's implementation of ScriptRunner:

- [Strips the header](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/807dbe557a47b6944a7d352c0316bcd78733f473/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/util/SourceFile.scala#L69) of multiline shebang for you down to `#!`
- Wraps your code in the anonymous outer class template listed above
- Writes a temporary scala file
- Compiles the scala file to a temporary directory
- Executes the compiled code
- Cleans up the temporary directory and script
- Exits the program with an exit code

You could write your own external bit of code that also does the same, in any language you want, and then `exec` your external code on one line, also. Or you can embed the functionality inside the script itself using multiline shebang syntax, like this example adapted from the Go sample on [this page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiline_shebang):

Debug version, printing commands via `sh -x`, and not actually deleting anything:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
scriptfile=`basename $0`
classname="${scriptfile%.*}"
scalafile="${classname}.scala"
sed -e '1,12d' -e "s/%scala_class_name%/${classname}/" < "$0" > $scalafile
scalac $scalafile
echo todo: rm $scalafile
scala $classname "$@"
STATUS=$?
echo todo: rm "${classname}*.class"
exit $STATUS
######## Scala code starts on line 13
object %scala_class_name% {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        class A
        val foo = classOf[A]
        println(foo.newInstance())
    }
}
```

The reason I included a debug version is that you probably want to just use this as a starting point. For example, one might want to do more setup or cleanup depending on what else is in the script, including:

- Edit the jvm args, including the classpath
- Create a whole temporary directory if there are multiple classes expected in the scripts
- More sed/awk of the embedded scala itself depending on passed in arguments
- etc.

That said here's a "it should just work, but I make no guarantees" version of the above, that cleans up after itself:

```
#!/bin/sh
scriptfile=`basename $0`
classname="${scriptfile%.*}"
scalafile="${classname}.scala"
sed -e '1,12d' -e "s/%scala_class_name%/${classname}/" < "$0" > $scalafile
scalac $scalafile
rm $scalafile
scala $classname "$@"
STATUS=$?
rm "${classname}*.class"
exit $STATUS
######## Scala code starts on line 13
object %scala_class_name% {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        class A
        val foo = classOf[A]
        println(foo.newInstance())
    }
}
```

### Citations:

- Chapter 14 of [Programming Scala: Scala Tools, Libraries, and IDE Support](http://techbus.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/scala/9780596801908/scala-tools-libraries-and-ide-support/349)

### Conflict of interest disclaimers for linking to commercial books:

Original answerer does not work for Oreilly, but is an avid consumer. ;)

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. Any idea on how to create such an inner class (A) that has a no-args constructor? Turns out I need to pass a Class reference to a library that itself calls newInstance(), so I can't modify that call...

Comment: Updated with an example that allows foo.newInstance(), and used updated rep to finally fix links. Thanks!