# How to force scalac to generate a static final field?

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

When defining vals on a companion object like this:

```
object Foo { val bar = 3 }
```

Scala generates static final methods:

```
$ scalac Foo.scala && javap Foo
public final class Foo {
  public static int bar();
}
```

Is there a way to make it generate a static field instead of a static method?

FWIW, I need it since I have existing compiled Java code and I need to preserve binary compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way at the moment to have Java-like static fields in Scala whether they are final or not. See explanation here for example: [Why doesn't Scala have static members inside a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302206/why-doesnt-scala-have-static-members-inside-a-class).

That's one of the reasons Akka is not written 100% in Scala: http://www.infoq.com/interviews/klang-akka

> So what is Akka write in it?
>
> Akka is not one hundred percent Scala because some constructs you
>   can’t really express in Scala for performance reasons, so static
>   fields for example, so when you need to do some tricky stuff with
>   concurrency you need to have static fields, so I think it’s like
>   ninety percent Scala and then we have some Java stuff just because we
>   have to.

You can do Java/Scala interop on the Java side, i.e. create some sort of adapters in your case.

There are existing implementations for `static fields`, but it's not clear when we'll get it: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4581.

I can't find a way to make this import compile: `import scala.annotation.static`. Maybe it's not in my Scala version or is disabled by default. Otherwise this would be the answer:

```
object Foo { @static final val bar: Int = 3 }
```